# Include image in data frame R

Tags: r, graphics

I have a data frame in R, something like this

```
       Score   Result
1       1       Pass       
2       0.8     Pass       
3       1       Pass       
4       0.5     Fail        
5       0.3     Fail        
6       0.2     Fail
```

Depending upon the value of Result (pass or fail), I would like to display thumbs-up or thumbs-down image when I write the data frame to the PDF.

I don't want to use knitr or shiny. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could define your own cell function in grid.table,

[image]

```
d <- read.table(textConnection("Score   Result
1       1       Pass       
2       0.8     Pass       
3       1       Pass       
4       0.5     Fail        
5       0.3     Fail        
6       0.2     Fail"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(png)
up <- rasterGrob(readPNG("up.png"), height = unit(1,"line"))
down <- rasterGrob(readPNG("down.png"), height = unit(1,"line"))

cell_grob <- function (label, parse = FALSE, col = "black", fontsize = 12, ...) 
{
  switch(label, "Pass" = up, "Fail" = down, 
         grid::textGrob(label = label, ...))

}

custom <- ttheme_default(core = list(fg_fun = cell_grob))
grid.newpage()
grid.table(d, theme = custom)
```

Comment: fg_fun  doesn't seem to work  in my R version. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I am getting the below error when I tried to update the grid Extra package ‘gridExtra’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
Warning in file(con, "w") :
  cannot open file '/home/josvikas/workspace/build/CRAN_gridExtra/CRAN_gridExtra-2.0.0_R3/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/private/gridExtra/install/lib64/R/library/gridExtra/doc/index.html': No such file or directory
Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing vignettes failed

Comment: How to disable building vignettes in the Make file?

Comment: @TwinklingStar I don't know what the problem is, but this is not the best place to discuss it. Please post a separate question with the exact steps you've taken, your sessionInfo() and platform, and try to update R if possible.